# Table View in Popover Won't Scroll When Over AGSMapView

Tags: uitableview, uipopovercontroller, arcgis, esri

I'm using the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/runtime-ios-sdk/), and I have a subclass of `UITableViewController` that I'm presenting in a popover; the base view of the main view controller being displayed is an `AGSMapView` with an `AGSGraphicsLayer` (`AGSSimpleRenderer` attached). When the popover is presented, there is no ability to select a cell, and scrolling is extremely limited. When I change the base view controller's view from an `AGSMapView` to a blank `UIView`, the table view in the popover works perfectly.

My `viewDidLoad:` is as follows:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.layerDelegate = self;
self.mapView.calloutDelegate = self;
self.mapView.callout.delegate = self;

// Create an instance of a tiled map service layer.
AGSTiledMapServiceLayer *tiledLayer = [[AGSTiledMapServiceLayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"]];

// Add it to the map view.
[self.mapView addMapLayer:tiledLayer withName:@"Tiled Layer"];

AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol *simpleMarkerSymbol = [AGSSimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol];
self.graphicsLayer.renderer = [AGSSimpleRenderer simpleRendererWithSymbol:simpleMarkerSymbol];

// Add graphics layer to the map view.
[self.mapView addMapLayer:self.graphicsLayer withName:@"Graphics Layer"];
```

Could this be a bug in the `AGSMapView` implementation, and if so, how do I go about reporting it?

Thanks in advance.

Related: [Sister Question in the Esri Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/86715-UITableView-in-Popover-Won-t-Scroll-When-Over-AGSMapView)

**EDIT**

I determined that the issue is fairly difficult to reproduce, so I added `mapViewDidLoad:` to add current location. This causes the issue to occur without fail. My code is as follows:

```
- (void)mapViewDidLoad:(AGSMapView *)mapView {
    [self.mapView.locationDisplay startDataSource];
    self.mapView.locationDisplay.autoPanMode = AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanModeDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was revealed to be a bug in the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS. Esri Support contacted me and told me that it will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to make the main view of your view controller a `UIView` and then add both the `AGSMapView` and your popover as subviews of the base `UIView`.

Comment: Can you add code to illustrate what you mean? I still can't seem to get this to work. In the storyboard, I place an `AGSMapView` on top of the `UIView` in the view controller, hook it up to the correct outlet, and in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, I add the popover controller's `contentViewController`'s view as a subview of `self.view` (if `[segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]` of course). This still does not solve the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question with a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: Your question said that when the main view on your VC was a simple UIView, then the table worked ok.  What I was suggesting was that you make that change again, make the main view and UIView.  Then add the map view as a subview of that main view.  Then for popovers with table views (that where the problem is right?), add them as subviews of the simple UIView, not as subviews of the map view.  Use `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` where view is the main UIView. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but i solve this with adding graphic layer after TiledLayer loaded not in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)layerDidLoad:(AGSLayer *)layer
{
     NSLog(@"layer %@ loaded",layer.name);
     if(!self.graphicLayer)
     {
          self.graphicLayer = [AGSGraphicsLayer graphicsLayer];    
          [self.mapView addMapLayer:self.graphicLayer withName:@"Graphic Layer"];
     }
}
```